# python: a shorter way to append values

Tags: python

```
  results_histogram_total=list(numpy.histogram(freq,bins=numpy.arange(0,6.1,.1))[0])
  sum_total=sum(results_histogram_total)
  big_set=[]
  for i in results_histogram_total:
    big_set.append(100*(i/sum_total)
```

is there a shorter way i can write the for loop to append the values?

Comment: How is that too long? Looks fine to me.

Comment: btw do i need to declare big_set=[] ???

Comment: if you want to **append** to your weirdly named list `bit_set`, then you do indeed need to **initialize** it to some list (there's no "declaring"!).  However, you can just **build** the list in one gulp, quite simply -- see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For *appending*, replace the loop with:

```
big_set.extend(100.0 * i / sum_total for i in results_histogram_total)
```

however, it's best to replace all the last three lines with just:

```
big_set = [100.0 * i / sum_total for i in results_histogram_total]
```

Also, I would advise to **not** call a list "something **set**" -- it's very confusing disinformation.  But, this is just a bit of naming style advice;-).

Comment: For the former, yes, as you are calling a method (`extend`) of the list, and it needs to be defined in order to exist.
For the latter, no, as Python is a dynamically typed language and does not require variables to be declared before they are defined.